# Passing the id of an element into a Rails hidden_field form helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a Rails app, and I want to capture a piece of information and submit it when a user saves a form (that in real life makes a comment).

This seems perfectly suited for the `hidden_field` helper from what I have read. However, the "hidden info" I need to include is not something as simple as a text input somewhere on the page.

**What I'm Asking:** In my view, a blog post is rendered using a Markdown gem. Every header tag is given a unique ID in the DOM that you won't see below (i.e. `<h1 id="toc_0">`, `<h3 id="toc_1">`.

A user clicks on the header, and it opens a comment box to the right. When that comment box is saved, I want it to save this id as a string in an existing column called `:location`.

I have added a `hidden_field` line in my form; however, it is not capturing anything. Is it possible to capture the id of this clicked element so I can save it to my table?

**The View**

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
            <h2 id="title"><%= post.title %></h2>
            <p id="category"><%= post.category %></p>
            <div id="paragraph"><%= markdown(post.content) %></div>    
    <% end %>
</div> 

  <!-- jQuery hides this and it toggles next to the clicked paragraph -->
    <div class="exampleToggle">
        <%= form_for :comments do |f| %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :post %><br>
                    <%= f.text_area :post, class: "form-control" %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <h5 id="username">Username</h5>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control" %>
                </div>
            </div>

            <%= f.hidden_field :location, :id => "hiddenPicker"%>

    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-success-outline" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
</div>

  <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.exampleToggle').hide();
        var whatever = document.getElementsByClassName("exampleToggle");
        $("h3").click(function(){
             $('.exampleToggle').show();
             $(this).prepend(whatever);
              $("form:not(.filter) :input:visible:enabled:first").focus();
            });
        });

</script>
```

Comment: Just to make sure I got this right, when a `h3` is clicked, you want to fill in the hidden field with id of `hiddenPicker` with the id of the `h3`?

Comment: @CarlMarkham That is correct. I want to supply the corresponding id so it can be saved in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **jQuery** to get the ID of the `H3` once it is clicked and pass it to the hidden field:

```
$(function () {
  $('h3').on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('input#hiddenPicker').val(id);
  });
});
```